# send jquery knob through a socket

Tags: jquery, sockets

i am a little lost as to how to access the output of jquery knob. I understand I need to create a variable that holds the output of the dial, and then shoot that into the socket.

i don't know how to access the .dial.change property. inside the function that is described as v.

```
<script>
    $(function() {

        $(".dial").knob({
    'min':100,
    'max':300, 
   'change' : function (v) { 
                        console.log(v);                
                       },

      'release' : function (v) {}                   
   });



  var logKnob = .dial.change.value; // i know this is incorrect

  var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.5:8081');
    socket.send(logKnob);



        });
</script>

<input type="text" value="75" class="dial">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use jQuery's [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) function:

```
var socket = new WebSocket('ws://192.168.1.5:8081');
socket.send( $('.dial').val() );
```

Of course, it's worth noting that this will only ever send the socket when the DOM is ready (because the code is placed outside of any event listener). It would be better to send the socket inside the `change` callback of the `knob` plugin.

Doing this passes back the value as a parameter for the callback, so there's no need to call `val()`, since it will be explicitly passed to your anonymous function anyway:

```
$(function() {

    var sock = new WebSocket( 'ws://192.168.1.5:8081' );

    $('.dial').knob({
        'min': 100,
        'max': 300, 
        'change': function ( val )
        { 
            sock.send( val );
        },
   });
});
```